# single login but different authorization

Tags: java, spring, authentication, authorization

I have two java web applications,each of them has same database.
Users work both of them with two login pages for any of that application.
Users want sigle login page another hand when an user login to any of that application,it is valid for another of those.
My problem is that an user has two different authorization in any of those application another hand
I want single login page but different authorization for any of those applications.
Is there a technology of java solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Spring SAML can be your option.
Have a look here: http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/

You will need to setup an IdP (Identity provider) server responsible for owning user identities and credentials. Users will actually authenticate with the IdP and then a SAML token will be pass to your web applications (Service Provider)

1. SAML supports Single Sign On. It means: a user can log in at one place in your 1st application and visit another application without re-enter his username and password.
2. Based on attributes of users in SAML token, your application's access control can be made. For example, you can add a user to different groups with different access permissions and these permissions will be embedded in SAML token.